# How to check model of motherboard and motherboard support for RAID

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, raid

I am following a [guide](http://www.pcworld.com/article/132877/RAID.html?page=2) to implementing a RAID 1+0 to my laptop when I encountered problems regarding the installation of the RAID adapter . I am suppose to check if my motherboard supports RAID and do certain steps if it does not .

1) How do i check what model of motherboard I am using from the desktop ??

2) How do i check if this motherboard supports RAID ??

I am using a [Ailenware mx14](http://www.dell.com/sg/p/alienware-m14x/pd) with Windows 7 as my OS

Comment: It's very unlikely your laptop motherboard has a raid controller. Alienware support staff should be able to confirm.  Did it come with multiple HDDs?

Comment: @Ramhound I only have 1 HDD currently which is my C drive